# new keyword not forcing hiding - OOP C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, dependency-injection

I have the following scenario:

I want to mock an interface so I can unit test my app. I am trying not to create a new mock class implementing my interface but creating a new class that inherits the original concrete class and use new keyword to force new behaviour when that method would be called. But for some reason, the concrete classs' method is being called and not the class that I created (as a mock)

Following Code:

```
public interface IMyService 
{ 
    Model GetModelData(int id)
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public Model GetModelData(int id)
    { 
       //call to db     
    }
}

public class MyService2 : MyService
{
    public MyService2()
        : base(new MyRepository())
    {    
    }

    public new Model GetModelData(int id)
    { 
        return new Model();
    }
}
```

Injecting dependency:

```
x.ForRequestedType<IMyService>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<MyService2>();
```

Retrieving the concrete class : on debugging I can see myService points to MyService2 class but the method executes on MyService class.

```
_myServie = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyService>();
                Model modelData = _myServie.GetModelData(5);
```

Comment: Which dependency injection framework are you using?

Comment: @dav_i: By looking at the code, I assume StructureMap. The `ObjectFactory` is something that StructureMap has.

Comment: @Avais, please explain why you are creating a mock that derives from the real implementation instead of creating a mock solely based on the interface. What your doing is fragile and makes testing more complicated. If you need to include the implementation, there is certainly something wrong with your design.

Comment: Yes, it is structure map.
@Steven: That is because, I dont want my MyService2 class to implement all methods on Interface MyInterface1 (as it is huge) I only want to mock one method I would be using with my changes (no call to repository)

Comment: @Avais: If your interface is use, you are violating the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and this is clearly causing you trouble. Interfaces should be small and focused.

Comment: @Steven: Thanks mate. But the actual interface is companys code and it is huge and focussed on relevant business methods, is there any way I can mock just one method of that interface without having to implement all methods? Thanks

Comment: @Avais: It doesn't matter that you can't change that interface. What matters is that your application code directly depends upon an interface that it didn't define itself. This is an error since according to [APP&P](https://amzn.to/1DCAll2) "clients [...] own the abstract interfaces". So what you should do is make small interfaces specific to your application and the implementations (proxies) can forward the call to the ugly company wide interface definition. DO NOT pollute your application code and test code with this nonsense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just using `new` creates a new method without associating it with the interface. You're using the interface in your real code (I assume) so you want the binding of the interface method to the new method. To do that, you have to declare that you're implementing the interface again. Here's an example showing the difference:

```
using System;

interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

class Normal : IFoo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Normal.Bar");
    }
}

class Extended1 : Normal
{
    public new void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Extended1.Bar");
    }
}

class Extended2 : Normal, IFoo
{
    public new void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Extended2.Bar");
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IFoo x = new Extended1();
        IFoo y = new Extended2();

        x.Bar();
        y.Bar();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Normal.Bar
Extended2.Bar
```

So if you change your class declaration to:

```
public class MyService2 : MyService, IMyService
```

you should find it just works. I can't say I'm a big fan of this approach, mind you - anything within `MyService` which calls the method will call its own implementation *unless* it happens to call through an `IMyService`-type reference. You could make the interface implementation in your concrete class virtual and *override* it in your subclass instead; that would be better in someways but worse in others. Basically, this sort of "half-inheritance" feels pretty fragile to me.

I suspect it would be cleaner if you had an abstract base class that both your real implementation and your test implementation derived from...

Comment: Ah, that's a little trixy as `new MyService() is IMyService` and `new MyService2() is IMyService` without redeclaring. Interesting corner-case.

Comment: But then I will have to implement all methods of IMyService interface which I want to avoid. Is there any way so I can only mock one method of that interface? Thanks

Comment: @Avais: No you don't need to reimplement all those methods. Any you don't reimplement will just use the existing implementation in the base class.

Comment: Thanks guys, this works :)
@JonSkeet: Thanks mate, yes I did not need to reimplement the interface methods just the one I intend to hide :)
I am so happy. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is making the method on MyService virtual and overriding it in MyService2. Like so:

```
public interface IMyService 
{ 
    Model GetModelData(int id)
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public virtual Model GetModelData(int id)
    { 
       //call to db     
    }
}

public class MyService2 : MyService
{
    public MyService2()
        : base(new MyRepository())
    {    
    }

    public override Model GetModelData(int id)
    { 
        return new Model();
    }
}
```

This way, if the method is overridden in the child class, then the child classes method will be called, otherwise the base class will consume the method call.

Comment: IMyService is business part with many more methods. I just want to mock, 'GetModeldata' method without having to implement the interface on my new 'mock' class. Is there any way? Thanks

Comment: Like I say, if you are inheriting from a class, not just your interface, make it virtual on your base class. In your new class, just override the one method and all other methods will be the same as the base class. You will be able to test this single method in this way.